# JavaScript Reduce Inside Map

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I am trying to sort an array of objects based on the sum of one of the object's property. Essentially, like this:

```
array = [
          {
            id:4,
            tally: [1, 3, 5]
          },
         {
            id: 6,
            tally: [2, 3, 6]
         },
         {
            id: 9,
            tally: [2, 1, -1]
         }
]
```

If we sum the corresponding `tally`s, we'd get 9, 11, and 2 respectively, in which case I would like something like this:

```
array = [
          {
            id:6,
            tally: [2, 3, 6]
          },
         {
            id: 6,
            tally: [1, 3, 5]
         },
         {
            id: 9,
            tally: [2, 1, -1]
         }
]
```

I know it's some combination of `map`, `reduce` but I'm struggling to see how to code it up in the nice proper React format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first calculate sum in every object using `map` and `reduce` then sort that new array using `sort` method and then just remove sum property with another `map` method

```js
const array = [{
    id: 4,
    tally: [1, 3, 5]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    tally: [2, 3, 6]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    tally: [2, 1, -1]
  }
]

const sorted = array
  .map(({ tally, ...rest }) => ({
    sum: tally.reduce((r, e) => r + e, 0), tally, ...rest
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => b.sum - a.sum)
  .map(({ sum, ...rest }) => rest)

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sort`:

```js
var arr=[{id:4,
          tally: [1, 3, 5]},
         {id: 6,
          tally: [2, 3, 6]},
         {id: 9,
          tally: [2, 1, -1]}
]

var result =arr.sort((a,b)=>{
    aa = a.tally.reduce((acc,elem)=>acc+elem,0);
    bb = b.tally.reduce((acc,elem)=>acc+elem,0);
    return bb-aa;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fist accumulate the sums into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where each key is the `id` of an object and each value is the sum of that object's `tally` array. You can use `.reduce()` to calculate the sum. Here the `acc` is an accumulated value which starts off as 0 and gets added to every time the reduce callback is called.

Once you have the sums for each object you can sort based on the sums of each object using `.sort()` like so:

```js
const array = [{ id: 4, tally: [1, 3, 5] }, { id: 6, tally: [2, 3, 6] }, { id: 9, tally: [2, 1, -1] }];
const sumMap = new Map(array.map(
  ({id, tally}) => [id, tally.reduce((acc, n) => acc+n, 0)])
);
const res = array.sort((a, b) => sumMap.get(b.id) - sumMap.get(a.id));

console.log(res);
```